# Angular2 integration with JSP or javaEE

Tags: java, angular, rest, jsp

How can we integrate Angular2+ apps with java technologies such as JSP ?

Also, is it a good way to integrate angular apps directly with java technologies or is it better to use by creating java APIs(restful API's).

Comment: You can work two ways: First -> make separate web service and another app for Angular and run those two app into different port
Second: you can put the angular content into your application webContent folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use with spring boot.but JSP is not good idea.once build with angular code copy into spring boot in index.html

Jhipster is also good solution 
https://www.jhipster.tech/